# to get time in GMT from locale

Tags: java, datetime, locale

I am facing one issue.
Suppose the user is logging to my website at 2014-12-24 01:00 am from China, so i stored his logged in time. Now if he logged in again from France at so i need to show his last logged in time as per timezone of France, 2014-12-23 17:00 as per GMT. I am having locale information of user from where he is logging in.
This is my code:

```
String lastLoggedIndatetime = "2014-11-23 04:01" ; //time of last logged in from China; 
Locale locale = Locale.FRANCE; //suppose this i am getting as args from Http request

SimpleDateFormat loggedInDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(locale);
TimeZone loggedInTimeZone = c.getTimeZone();
System.out.println("Time Zone is "+ c.getTimeZone().getDisplayName());

SimpleDateFormat gmtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm");
TimeZone gmtTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
gmtFormat.setTimeZone(gmtTimeZone);
try {
    String lastLoggedIndatetimeAsPerFrance = loggedInDateFormat.format(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm").parse(lastLoggedIndatetime.trim()));
    String gmtDateTime= gmtFormat.format(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm").parse(lastLoggedIndatetimeAsPerFrance.trim()));
    System.out.println("last logged in Date as per France is "+ lastLoggedIndatetimeAsPerFrance + "  TimeZone is "+loggedInTimeZone);
    System.out.println("GMT Date is "+ gmtDateTime + "  TimeZone is "+ gmtTimeZone); 
    //formattedDate.append(gmtDateTime)
    //.append(" - "); //" - " is delimiter for date
} catch (ParseException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Demo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

And output is :

```
Time Zone is India Standard Time
last logged in Date as per France is 2014-01-23 04:01  TimeZone is sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Calcutta",offset=19800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=6,lastRule=null]

GMT Date is 2014-31-22 10:31  TimeZone is sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null]
```

it is not showing time as per france but as per India (currently me in India). Also GMT is as per India, not as per France.

Comment: You are not passing `locale` information to `SimpleDateFormat`, can you try to pass the `locale`

Comment: still not working, getting same o/p :: Time Zone is India Standard Time

Answer (score 1):

you need to set `TimeZone` in `Calendar` instance before you do any operation.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(locale);
c.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Paris")); //like this
TimeZone loggedInTimeZone = c.getTimeZone();
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot derive the time zone from the Locale. The Locale can be selected by the user for their browser regardless of where the user actually is. Additionally, many Locales span many time zones. If you want to know the time zone of the user you can try to guess by looking up location of the ip address or you can offer to allow the user to tell you where they are.